# how to add timestamp to child document when indexing in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, timestamp, parent-child

For a parent-child relationship index in Elasticsearch, the parent and children documents in the case were not added in the same time. A new child document may be added after parent exists.

By following the steps described in [Automatically adding a timestamp to documents](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/dec-12th-2018-en-elasticsearch-automatically-adding-a-timestamp-to-documents/159314) , the ingest_timestamp field was found to be added to parent documents, but it didn't work for the children document indexing.

```
PUT _ingest/pipeline/my_timestamp_pipeline
{
  "description": "Adds a field to a document with the time of ingestion",
  "processors": [
    {
      "set": {
        "field": "ingest_timestamp",
        "value": "{{_ingest.timestamp}}"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Is it convenient to add creation time for child documents?

Answer (score 0):

It was an invalid use in go but the error was not print out. After printing error, it was found that the indexing actually didn't happen. After fixing the issue, indexing is now working. The pipeline works for both parent and child documents.